# Who is the "one" who can defeat Mephisto?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, mephisto

In the "Silver Surfer: Judgment Day" graphic novel, on page 58, Mephisto is battling with Galactus and says the following thing:

> I am Mephisto! Only ONE has the power to defy me, and next to him you are less than a smoldering cinder in the furnace of the damned!

See:

[image: Mephisto threats]

To whom is Mephisto referring? There are surely a number of beings in the Marvel universe that are not only able to defy him but have actually done it. Who is Mephisto singling out here?

Comment: [God?](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/one-above-all/4005-44473/)

Answer (score 3):

There is someone referred to as the "[One-Above-All](http://hero.wikia.com/wiki/One-Above-All_(Marvel))". This entity created the Living Tribunal who was seen as one of the most powerful beings in the universe. Anyone that could create someone like that would probably be up there on the power scale.

Comment: Is this really who Mephisto is referring to? I'm not convinced. It's a very out-of-the-blue comment. How many other references to the One Above All are contemporary of this graphic novel in 1988?

Comment: Look at how ONLY ONE is in caps. Makes a case for this entity. If not, then the Living Tribunal